# How to retrieve data in brackets via JSON DECODE

Tags: php, json

I'm using JSON DECODE to get an array out of a dataset exactly like the one described here: https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/api/callback/.

Most of the data is getting fine into arrays, but I can get the [operations] data into an array - most likely because of the square brackets in the dataset.

This is my codeline:

```
$callback_brand = $obj['metadata']['brand']; // WORKS FINE
$callback_amount = $obj['operations']['amount']; // DOESN'T WORK
```

Anyone?

Comment: can you post the raw json content? may be the content of operations field isn't a json sub-object... I can also infer that it is a json array because there is the 's' in operations, which means maybe that you have to access its objects like $obj['operations'][0]

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)
$callback_amount = $obj['operations'][0]['amount'];

Comment: Good to know! Cheers :-)